Extract serialized json array in MariaDB database as comma separated values
I have a table with a column called "meta_value".  The CMS that uses this table stores multiselect checkbox fields as a serialized json array in the database.
Here is the serialized json array:
a:2:{i:0;s:19:"Government projects";i:1;s:16:"Private Projects";}
And here is the array that this serialization represents (unserialized):
Array
(
    [0] => Government projects
    [1] => Private Projects
)

I need to be able to do a database query directly and pull any amount values together into a string such as:
"Government projects, Private Projects"
But the serialization is causing json_extract to not work....
I was trying the below sql before I realized my data was serialized:
SELECT post_id, json_extract(meta_value, '$[0]') AS quota 
FROM `wpdb_postmeta`  
WHERE meta_id = 231502
ORDER BY `wpdb_postmeta`.`meta_id`  DESC;

I do realize that the above (if the data hadn't been serialized) would have just returned the first value in the json data but I was trying to start from there and then figure it out.
Can anyone help me figure out how to unserialize the data and then extract it into a neat comma separated value string as shown above?
I can't use any PHP because I'm writing queries that will directly be used within a Wordpress plugin so I can only work with SQL queries sadly enough.

There isn't really any good way to parse serialized data directly in MySQL.

Aren't WP plugins usually written in PHP? Why can't you call unserialize() in the plugin?

Whatever that is, it isn't json. "Serialized json" is a strange term, json is a serialization format already.

It's just a serialized array, created using PHP's serialize() function.
